# Closures over Christmas in Hong Kong/Macau?

Tags: hong-kong, public-holidays, macau, closures

I'll be in Hong Kong over the Christmas holiday (Dec 20-28). I will spend part of that time (not sure when) in Macau.

What sorts of closures should I expect over this period?

Comment: Welcome. I know you're not that new a user, but generally posts are one question per post.  Could you perhaps split into 'closures over Christmas in HK/Macau' and 'events over Christmas in HK/Macau' - and have a read of the [help] about how to word these - you are currently risking people closing it as being 'too broad' as there are too many possible answers.

Comment: Done! Sorry about that. I'm used to answering questions, not asking them.

Comment: all good, we learn as we go :) Thanks for the update, I'm going to tweak it a bit, let me know if that's a problem.

Comment: The casinos will be open all the time, they never close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only possibly on the 23rd, most likely not even then.

First of all, shops and malls are usually open on Public Holidays in Asia. Second of all, there are [some public holidays](http://portal.gov.mo/web/guest/info_detail?infoid=180821) during the 20-28th December, but they will not affect tourists. Malls and Shops will be open, except maybe for a couple of privately run restaurants or shops. However, since Macau lives to a huge extent from tourism, the vast majority of places will be open. If you have a special place you want to visit, you might want to check online whether that place is open, and then book a table as well.

Comment: On the 23rd? On a Tuesday?

Comment: Yes, check the link for a description

Comment: I did, but the 23rd isn't listed. The 22nd is. Is it like New Year's where people celebrate the night before?

Comment: I am not sure where you are looking, but the December 23rd id connected to the Macau Special Administrative Region Establishment and not to Christmas.

Comment: I FOUND IT! I was just completely overlooking it. That page is confusing. So the 22, 24, and 25 are NOT public holidays even though they're on the list?

Comment: I wish I could give you an "extra patience" badge or something.

Comment: Sorry, I just scrolled down and did not see that there are two parts to the list. I would not expect most shops (except some private run ones to be closed over the holidays.

Comment: In Hong Kong, it is a public holiday for both 25th and 26th of December. http://www.gov.hk/en/about/abouthk/holiday/2014.htm However, it still will not affect tourists.